# Swift syntax for block with completionHandler... in delegate method

Tags: ios, objective-c, closures, block, swift

This is a wrinkle on the regular NSURLSession completion block problem, which I'm having a heck of a time resolving into Swift syntax.  The method is the authentication delegate callback, which is invoked on auth challenge; the developer calls the completion block with NSURLCredential, NSError.

The Objective-C method looks like this:

```
-(void) provideUsernamePasswordForAuthChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)authChallenge completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLCredential *, NSError *))completionHandler{

    NSURLCredential* credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"myname" 
                                                             password:@"mypass" 
                                                          persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    completionHandler(credential, nil);
}
```

The closest I think I've gotten in Swift, is this:

```
func provideUsernamePasswordForAuthChallenge(authChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!,  completionHandler:(() -> (NSURLCredential?, NSError?)) {

    var cred = NSURLCredential(user: "myname", password: "mypass", persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
    return (cred, nil)
})
```

But, it's still barfing.  Any recommendations?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. a void function is (Type1, Type2)->()
2. you need to add the ->() for the method itself
3. You need to call completionHandler with (cred, nil), not return a tuple

   ```
   func provideUsernamePasswordForAuthChallenge(authChallenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge!,  completionHandler:(NSURLCredential?, NSError?)->()) ->() {

      var cred = 
         NSURLCredential(user: "myname", password: "mypass", 
            persistence: NSURLCredentialPersistence.ForSession)
      completionHandler(cred, nil)
   }
   ```

Comment: This could be cleaned up even a little bit more: (1) the method itself doesn't need a return type since it is Void (so you can leave off the `-> ()` in the method signature), and (2) since for `NSURLCredential` the type of the `persistence` argument is known, you can just provide the option that you want to use, `.ForSession`

Answer (score 1):

This code may help ->

```
 AFAppDotNetAPIClient.sharedClient().GET("User", parameters:nil, success:{ (task : NSURLSessionDataTask!, JSON: AnyObject!) in
        // within block....

        }, failure:nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your type is backwards — you want the completion handler to take two arguments and return none, but you've defined it as a function that takes no arguments and returns a pair. Flop the two sides of the arrow.